Align in a standalone
I'd like to create a single page with arbitrary long equations. For that, I used standalone with varwidth like this:
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  
\end{align*}
\end{document}

This works if I use $…$, but not with align, as the equation is pushed after a huge blank space:

Any idea what I'm missing?

why use align when there is no alignment?  removing the varwidth and using $ would be much simpler and much faster

An alignment is always as wide as its containing page so doesn't make it easy for varwidth to adjust, especially if you give a target of \maxdimen it is a lot simpler for standalone to fit a tightly fitting page if you use $ and aligned rqather than align however

\documentclass[varwidth=180cm,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D =  A = B = C = D = X 
\end{align*}
\end{document}


Oh I see, thanks, \[\begin{aligned}…\end{aligned}\] does the job indeed, thanks! (but for some reasons your mwe is different) And in real life I do use the & …\\ &\\ from align, hence my question.

no not \[ . Use \( or single $  so then you don't need varwidth, as it's inline math it  naturally has a width. Display math has no natural width, its natural width is "as wide as the page"

Oh really? In my test \[ does work. I was affraid not to have display-style with \(, but seems like \begin{aligned} restores display style, so both solutions work for me. Thanks!

@tobiasBora standalone probably handles \[ but the principle is right: that horizontal material has a natural width and vertical material does not
